# Android Studio Refresh Error - Cause: invalid type code: 04

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I opened my project in Android Studio 2.1.2. and get the error message:

```
Error:Cause: invalid type code: 04
```

The stack trace in the log shows the following

```
** INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/home/user/gradle/gradle-2.10'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:85)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:194)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:162)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:132)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:117)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:190)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:39922'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:79)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 04
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1380)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message.receive(Message.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.BaseSerializerFactory$ThrowableSerializer.read(BaseSerializerFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.BaseSerializerFactory$ThrowableSerializer.read(BaseSerializerFactory.java:146)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.DaemonMessageSerializer$FailureSerializer.read(DaemonMessageSerializer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.DaemonMessageSerializer$FailureSerializer.read(DaemonMessageSerializer.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:77)
    ... 24 more**
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467155/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu

Comment: That looks like a different error to me.

Comment: @barq see my answer below.

Comment: @barq post the code here.??

Comment: this may be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667820/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-04

Comment: This is an Android Studio error ,not something to do with my code. If anything it is the configuration of the project.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution for this? I've just started getting this error out of the blue myself.

Comment: Nope, still waiting for answers as well

Comment: I got this error when I had an invalid `compile project(':myproject')` under `dependencies{}` in my build.gradle